# Why does the state object in react not update properly? Expanded and collapsed version of object differ

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a picture of what I get on the console `<br><br>`
[image: Here is the picture of what I get on the console in chrome]

I am using React.js, and the object shown in the image is an element of an array that is part of the state object. I do not understand what is going on. The object shows what is expected of it when collapsed. But when I expand it using the right arrow button, the expanded version of the object gives this output. Can anyone please tell me what's going on here? I want to clarify that I did not use `setState` to update the state to this condition since I wanted to make sure that I avoid re-rendering.

here is the code for what I did to update the state

```js
if (this.props.currentNumberingScheme === 'a') {
  var edge = this.state.edgeList[i];
  edge.from.data = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(edge.from.data) + 64);
  edge.to.data = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(edge.to.data) + 64);
  console.log('GRAPH: updated edge', edge.from.data, edge.to.data);
  console.log('GRAPH: updated edge', this.state.edgeList[0].from.data, this.state.edgeList[0].to.data);
  console.log('GRAPH: transformed edge list', this.state.edgeList[0].from);
  console.log('GRAPH: updated edge', this.state.edgeList[0].from.data, this.state.edgeList[0].to.data);
}
```

when I log `edge.from.data` and `edge.to.data`, the output is in fact 'A' and 'B' (as expected). when I log `this.state.edgeList[0].from`, the phenomenon shown in the image takes place. Can anyone please clarify??

Comment: Can you please add code on what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the docs on [react state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html). Though that page doesn't explicitly address the issue you're facing.

The problem is that you define a variable `edge` from `this.state` like so:

```js
var edge = this.state.edgeList[i];
edge.from.data = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(edge.from.data)+64);
edge.to.data = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(edge.to.data)+64);
```

These second two lines modify the `edge` object but **do not** update `this.state` with their altered values. So when you log `edge.from.data` and `edge.to.data` you see the correct values, but when you log `this.state.edgeList[0].from` your displaying data the hasn't been updated.

Again, this is because when you mutate the object returned from `this.state` it **does not mutate `this.state`**.

If you do in fact require an object with direct mutability that does not re-render on change, you could probably use a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref). But likely you should just use a plain ol' object.